# I am found in every country

Tags: riddle

> I come in many colors and I am very thin
>
> I am found in every country, even in your home
>
> I am very important, you can be very creative with me
>
> I can even help you learn.

### What am I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or is it

> Ink, dye, pencils/crayons, money, glass, ...

I come in many colors and I am very thin

> All come in multiple colors and cen be thin. 
>  Liquids can be thin (depends on their viscosity) 
>  Pencils and crayons are often thin enough to fit in the hand of a kid. 
>  Coins or paper money are thin. Money often comes in multiple colors. 
>  Glass panes or windows are thin and can be colored.

I am found in every country, even in your home

> Pretty sure every country has these.

I am very important, you can be very creative with me

> Liquids/dye/paint/ink/pencils/crayons can be used to write down things or add some color to things. 
>  Coins or paper money are what you often use to buy things with. You can also use it in artistic ways.
>  Glass drinking flasses, windows, bottles, sunglasses. Important for storing stuff, preserving stuff or being able to see. Creativity with glass in lead or fancy bottles.

I can even help you learn.

> Liquids/dye/paint/ink/pencils/crayons can be used to print books, write things down, etc
>  Coins or paper money can be used to learn mathematics, economics and a little bit of history by showing the face of some monarch or other important historical characters. 
>  Can't read with glasses, glass in lead history, observing animals behind glass.

BTW

> Dit I mention that this question might be a little too broad?

Answer (score 12):

It is probably

> paper

I come in many colors and I am very thin

> colored sheets of paper

I am found in every country, even in your home

> everyone has some paper at home (at least toilet paper)

I am very important, you can be very creative with me

> you need it for a lot of things and can be used for art (paiting, writting...)

I can even help you learn.

> books are made of paper

Answer (score 6):

My Guess:

> A Flag

I come in many colors and I am very thin

> Describes a flag

I am found in every country, even in your home

> Every country has a flag, and people like to hang flags in their home

I am very important, you can be very creative with me

> flags are a national symbol, many flags have different meaning

I can even help you learn.

> many flags are made of components important to the history of the country and can be used to learn about the history of the country it represents

Comment: Probably nitpicky, but if this is the intended answer, that's pretty ignorant of a lot of countries and their culture. Both the second and last hint would not apply to my country and quite a few others I can think of.

Answer (score 5):

While the correct answer is likely mentioned, I wanted to add an alternative that also fits I think.

> Light

I come in many colors and I am very thin

> The Light spectrum, light comes in very small wave lengths

I am found in every country, even in your home

> Light can be found everywhere

I am very important, you can be very creative with me

> Light is important for most life, there have been incredible things done with light. Fireworks, Light shows, Screens

I can even help you learn.

> Fiber optics, screens, etc.